# How to add a company and position to a contact in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

How can I add information about a **company**, in which my contact is hired, and a **position**, he or she has there, using web version of Gmail? I can do this without any problems, using mobile version (Contacts application in Android), but I don't see proper fields in web version.

Here is an example of a contact added via web version:

[image]

As you can see, there is no information about position or compoany, nor any way to add it.

Here is the same contact, that I edited using "Contacts" application in Android:

[image]

As you can see, now even in web version of Gmail, fields for company and position are displayed and can be easily edited by user.

But, it seems, that when user has no access to mobile version, he or she can't add these two fields / information. Or am I missing something obvious? Is there any way to add them in Gmail web version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to Google Contacts, either by browsing to http://contacts.google.com, or from the dropdown menu top-left in Gmail:

[image: Gmail dropdown menu]

This will take you to a list of your contacts. Click on one contact, scroll to the bottom of the page, and find the *Add* button, and select *Title and company*:

[image: Select "Title and company"]

The cursor will now be placed in a field below your contact's name, where you can enter title and company info:

[image: Editing title and company]